# Migrating Mysql data into Elasticsearch using logstash for kibana

Tags: kibana

I'm new to kibana.I am working with data migration from MySQL to elasticsearch.How can i do this? Is using jdbc input plugin is the only process??

Here is the logstash.conf file where i specified the input and output:

```
 input {
   jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kibana"
    jdbc_user => "xxx"
    jdbc_password => "xxxxx"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/root/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM datalog"

}
 }
 output {
  elasticsearch {
      "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
   }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 }
```

after running the above file by using ./logstash -f logstash.conf we are getting the below error:

WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console

Comment: Try with the jdbc as input in Logstash conifg and ES as output. Ensure that the connection settings are correct. Add more details to the question if that doens't help.

Atm, it'd be hard for anyone to suggest an answer as we don't know what any of your settings look like

Comment: @MuhammadAli i have modified the question and added the code.if any corrections in the code please suggest me    -thanks

Comment: It seems like your "logstash.yml" is not found. Try and see if its in the right location. If not then add :)

Comment: I changed it.now ,the data is getting converted to elastic search but index is not getting generated.what can be the problem?

Comment: I think it's because you didn't specify the index in the logstash output config:

output {
 elasticsearch {
 
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   index => "INDEX_NAME :)"
   document_type => "nginx_logs"
 }
 # stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

Comment: I found the mistake i gave the elastic search IP as different so it hasn't worked for me.